# Tmux - how to preserve window name after join-pane

Tags: tmux

When I do `:join-pane -s :window-name` in tmux, and than `tmux !` to send window back it lost its name, is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Oh, and having mirror on other window in pane is also fine.

Comment: I'd like to know too... Also, when you do join-pane, does your current window keep its name ? If yes, how do you do this, because in my case, after a join-pane, the window is renamed "bash".